# Get ASCII character from number in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, ascii

my requirement is, when I input a number (say 01 - 100), I should be able to get the ASCII code value for that number.

Ex: 01 = A, 02 = B, 03 = C, so on...., 90 = Z, and if number is 91 = AA, 92 = AB, 93 = AC, etc...

All I could get from googling, etc...was to convert int to a char, get ASCII value, but that happens only while printing using "%c" but not able to save into a CHAR or STRING.

Ex:

```
int inputNumber=5;  
char getASCIICharValue = (char)inputNumber;  
printf("\n getASCIICharValue: %c  \n", getASCIINumberValue);  
// Above would print 'E' which is correct  
printf("\n getASCIICharValue as char: %s  \n", getASCIINumberValue);  
// Above results in a RUN-TIME error.
```

While printing it is printing the values properly but while saving it to String or Char it not able to.

---

really sorry for not posting my issue correctly, may be I couldn't put the question properly as this is my first post...

I am editing my post which may make it little clear...

input I would enter would be 1 (or any integer, say 1 - 100), and I should be able to get the ASCII representation of that number in decimal...

assuming 1 is 65, currently what I am doing is, I am first subtracting 1 and then add 65 to it...

for ex: if the input is 5, it would be 5 - 1 + 65  =

69, which represents uppercase letter E

same way if the input is 15, my output should be Uppercase O

hope this is little clear...

Comment: I don't know what conversion table you are referring to, but if `A` = `01`, it's probably not ASCII.

Comment: ASCII value of 'A' is 65 (decimal)... What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: There are many things wrong with your question. First of all, "01 = A .. 90 = Z" would mean that there are 90 letters in the alphabet,. right? And are you sure that "Above would print 'E'" is true?

Comment: @all: may be I couldn't put the question properly as this is my first post...

Comment: @Sudheer: you can edit it and make it clearer, so we can understand what you're after. We can't help you if we don't understand what you want.

Comment: I don't think it's how you put it that's the problem. Look at an [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/).

Comment: sorry for that,
  

In decimals 65 represents the Uppercase letter A...   


assuming that my input is a number as integer, say that could be anything in the range 01 to 100...  


I am assuming that if the input is 01, I would first subtract 1 and then add 65 to it, so for 5, it would be 5-1+65 = 69, which represents uppercase letter E...

Answer (score 1):

You're defining your own character encoding there.

Divide by ten and take modulo ten iteratively over to get the digits, then use

```
char to_ascii (int i) {
    return 'A' + i - 1;
}

// ...

assert (to_ascii(0x01) == 'A');

char buffer [20] = {0};
for (...) {
    buffer [i] = to_ascii (n);
}

printf (buffer);
```

How on earth did you get `90='Z'`?

Comment: `to_ascii(0)` produces `'A' + 0 - 1` which is `@`. So, encoding `100` would give `A@@`.

Comment: Yep, but that seems to follow from his poorly-specified problem.

Answer (score 1):

The runtime error you get is because `%s` requires a pointer to a null-terminated array of characters. You're passing a character instead. Doing this produces undefined behaviour. Luckily you're getting a runtime error, which makes the bug obvious.

It is not clear what you are trying to do here so have no idea what the best solution for this would be.

Answer (score 1):

**Hi, you can try this simple method :**

---

```
int main()
{
int i;
cin>>i;
cout<< (char)i <<"\n"; 

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* numToColumn(int n, char* outstr){
    char* p = outstr;
    while(n){
        *p++ = 'A' + ((n % 26 == 0)? 26 : n % 26) - 1;
        n = (n - 1) / 26;
    }
    *p = '\0';
    return strrev(outstr);//strrev is win32 not ANSI C
}

int main(){
    char buff[16];

    printf("%s\n", numToColumn( 1,buff));//A
    printf("%s\n", numToColumn( 5,buff));//E
    printf("%s\n", numToColumn(26,buff));//Z
    printf("%s\n", numToColumn(27,buff));//AA
    printf("%s\n", numToColumn(52,buff));//AZ
    printf("%s\n", numToColumn(53,buff));//BA
    return 0;
}
```